# How to remove palette colors heatmap

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

Is possible if heatmap palette(small rectangle on the right) to be removed?

this is my data

```
    a       b       c   
1   181 80  121 10  34 20
2   18 20   17 20   13 20
3   12 20   5 30    20 20
```

this is my gnuplot script

```
set term pos eps font 20
unset key
set nocbtics
set palette rgbformulae -7, 2, -7
set title "Faults"

set size 1, 0.5
set output 'heatmap2.eps'
YTICS="`awk 'BEGIN{getline}{printf "%s ",$1}' 'data2.dat'`"
XTICS="`head -1 'data2.dat'`"
set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) i-1 )
set for [i=1:words(YTICS)] ytics ( word(YTICS,i) i-1 )

set for [i=1:words(XTICS)] xtics ( word(XTICS,i) 2*i-1 )
plot "<awk '{$1=\"\"}1' 'data2.dat' | sed '1 d'" matrix every 2::1 w image, \
     '' matrix using ($1+1):2:(sprintf('%d', $3)) every 2 with labels
```

I want to remove the palette because I adjust the ploting colors by percentage of my data. So, I guess the palette on the right my table is now use anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is the `colorbox`. Just use

```
unset colorbox
```

to remove it.